# Replace function on Telegram

Tags: python-2.7, telegram

I'm trying to learn how to use the `replace` function on telegram. To do that, first i'm trying to make it work on a basic bot that repeats what a user says. So, the bot has to replace characters from the user's message, but it's not working. On this example, i'm trying to make my bot replace every "i" with "o" from a message, but it seems not to work.

```
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)


    if content_type == 'text':
        msg['text'].replace("i", "o")
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` function return result, try:

```
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)


    if content_type == 'text':
        msg['text'] = msg['text'].replace("i", "o")
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg['text'])
```